# Sum max values in a column based on two other columns

Tags: excel

I have three columns and I want the sum of the maximum values in `Col2` for each category in `Col1` where `Col3` is equal to x.

I am not able to add a 4th column to obtain the max first.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3  
a       3       x  
b       2       x  
c       2       x  
a       1       x  
b       3       x  
c       1       y  
a       2       y  
b       1       y  
c       3       y
```

In this example the answer I am looking for is 8:

- 3 for a,
- plus 3 for b,
- plus 2 for c.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Do you mind using UDF (ie macro can be activated on your worksheet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER with data in `A2:C10` and `D1`="x":

```
=SUM(IF(C2:C10=D1,IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,B2:B10,">"&B2:B10,C2:C10,D1)=0,B2:B10)))
```

but note that if there might be more than one max value for a category this sums multiple values. To sum unique max values per category you could try this alternative (also with CSE):

```
=SUM(IF(C2:C10=D1,(MATCH(A2:A10,IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,B2:B10,">"&B2:B10,C2:C10,D1)=0,A2:A10),0)=ROW(A2:A10)-MIN(ROW(A2:A10))+1)*B2:B10))
```

For example changing the first value from 3 to 1 gives 7 in the first formula and 6 in the second.

Comment: +1, Nicely done lori_m - I was aiming for something like that myself but couldn't get there.........

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Both work well and I could use the first because the maximum values are unique.  However, I do have a problem in that I have 30,000+ rows and it stops working somewhere between 3000 and 4000 rows, then I get "Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas".  Is there any way around this?

Comment: I've adjusted the formula to use the COUNTIFS function instead of the previous matrix approach. If this is still too slow I'd suggest writing a UDF using a dictionary to store the max values for each category.

Comment: thanks so much!  I ended up using the first formula (had the same problem with this one), managed to split the data into smaller sections